# Trying to send http request when i received firebase notification in flutter when app is in terminated state

Tags: flutter, dart, http, firebase-cloud-messaging

Getting an error when trying to send an HTTP request when I received a firebase notification in a Flutter when the app is in the terminated state.

**Error:**

```
E/flutter: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_messaging/unknown] Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

**Code format:**

```
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  httpRequestFromApi();
}
```

Comment: Please share the code.

Comment: @user18309290 added the dummy code, can you check?